# Concatting arguments after argv[2] NodeJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, npm

Edit: Mykola Borysyuk suggested i use [node-optimist](https://github.com/substack/node-optimist), unfortunately the author said its deprecated and to use [Minimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist).

After reading over it, i get the basic gist of it, but could someone show me an example?

---

As the title suggests I'm trying to combine multiple arguments for a command.

In other words...
Command goes `node init.js search <value>`.

Obviously I have no idea how many words the user will type after search, so i want to concat all of those 'arguments' into one string i can send to my search module.

I'm aware that I can use the following to "group" all arguments into independent strings

```
var cmd_string = process.argv.map( function(arg){
    return "'" + arg.replace(/'/g, "'\\''") + "'";
}).join(' ');
```

and this can output all arguments

```
process.argv.forEach((val, index) => {
    console.log(`${index}: ${val}`);
});
```

But i don't know how i'd go about extracting just the values after `process.argv[2];`

Bonus: If possible, could you also show me or link a way i'd be able to search for flags like `--option=value`

I spent a couple hours surfing Reddit and Google and came up short, so hopefully you can provide some insight.

Comment: https://github.com/substack/node-optimist  This module pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all args you can use

```
process.argv
```

for example:

```
node test.js arg1 arg2
```

process.argv will be like:

```
[NodeJs path, file path, arg1, arg2]
```

After you can do all you want with arguments, for example, join in string:

```
process.argv.join('');
```

To skip two elements you can use something like:

```
process.argv.splice(2, process.argv.length - 1)
```

or 
    process.argv.slice(2)

Comment: could you also show any example of how to do it with Minimist?